# Use Xpath to find element using starts-with in tag

Tags: xpath

My html:

```
<span script-data="MY_Product-4425"> This is my Product Name </span>
```

I'm trying to write an xpath that will find the text: "This is my Product Name, using the "script-data" tag, but the 4 digit value after My_Product is a dynamic number, so the only thing known is that the tag will start with: script-data="MY_Product-"

I've tried this, but its not working..

```
//tag[starts-with('script-data',"MY_Product-")]
```

How can I use starts-with for this?  Is there a better option?

Comment: Change `'script-data'` to `@script-data` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer from Arup Rakshit is not working, you probably have a default namespace.

Try this instead...

```
//*[local-name()='span'][starts-with(@script-data,'MY_Product-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below **XPATH 1.0**

```
  //span[starts-with(@script-data,'MY_Product')]
```

Comment: It should work, but it is returning 0 results, I'm playing with quotations to see if it makes a difference but it doesn't seem to

Comment: If you want only the text value inside the element, append `/text()` at the end and try `//span[starts-with(@script-data,'MY_Product')]/text()`